# How to build an Image Classification with distribution shift with PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, bounding-box, image-classification

i need to build an Image Classification with distribution shift with PyTorch.
The goal is to train a deep learning model to perform image classification on a provided dataset. The dataset consists of 8 different classes.
The main difficulty is the presence of a domain shift between training and test data.
This are my information:
• 8 different categories
• 1600 images for training
• 800 images for evaluation
• While in the train set images are characterized by different backgrounds,in test set all the images are collected with the same scenario.
The goal of the Homework 1 consists in solving a classification problem on the
provided dataset.

Data Explorer

• train folder, organized in one subfolder for each class from 0 to 7 (1.6k samples)
• test folder (800 samples)
• submission.csv: an example of submission file
example:
image, class
000.png,2
001.png,4
002.png,7
003.png,5
• test.csv contains the bounding boxes with respect to the original image size for each image of the test set
• train.csv contains the bounding boxes with respect to the original image size for each image of the train set
• Bbox are provided in the common format [min x, miny, max x, max y] of the Image Coordinates System.

I need an example of code to do this task.
Thank you!

I try to implement this code, but I don't think it works well.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/manuelalogiudice/sediovuolemaforseno